# PHP - strspn - scan allowed characters.. how to include : \n\r?

Tags: php

first let's remove the letter "`c`" from the "`$allowed=`" just to test something.

test.php

```
<?php
echo '
    <form method="post" action="/test.php">
    <textarea name="a">abc
    d</textarea>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

   $string = $_POST["a"];

   $allowed = 'abdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
   $scan = strspn($string, $allowed);

  if ($scan < strlen($string)){
    echo "problem occurs right after: $scan";
    echo "<br>the problematic character is:". substr($string, $scan,1);
  }

}

?>
```

let's see what the browser printed after "submit" is clicked on.

```
problem occurs right after: 2
the problematic character is:c
```

it works great. it says "c" is not in the allowed list. and thus a problem has been detected.

now let's put the "c" back in the "`$allowed`" list.

```
  $allowed = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
```

now let's submit the form again..

let's see what the browser printed.

```
problem occurs right after: 3
the problematic character is:
```

cool. it says the problem occurs after the 3rd character. in other words must be after the letter "c" from the html form. must be the "new line" thing.

there is no "new line" in the "`$allowed`" list. the error is logical.

but this is where it fails.. it says..

```
  the problematic character is:
```

it provides no data what so ever to work with.
how am i suppose to know what character needs to be added to the `$allowed` list if it does not tell me what the conflicting character is ?

the assumption seems to be "\n\r" conflict.

okay.. let's add "`\n\r`" to the "$allowed=" list to see what happens.

```
$allowed = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n\r';
```

there.. the all new.. brand new "$allowed".

let's hit submit again on the html form.

the browser's output:

```
problem occurs right after: 3
the problematic character is:
```

looks like the brand new "$allowed" list with the "\n\r" is a completely useless.

test.php is a single piece of php script. feel free to copy.. test it. it does not work.

first it has to work 
second it needs to TELL ME what the problematic character is.
so i can visually see it.

**UPDATE** 
first part of the answer comes from the comment posted

> '\n' in single quotes is considered as '\' and 'n' – u_mulder 2 m

unfortunately can not be chosen because it is simply a comment.

i am also looking for the other portion of the answer.. how to get it to print something visually on the browser so i know i am suppose to add

```
  \n\r
```

to the allowed list.

i could have been an alien from a different galaxy.. how would i know

\n\r needs to be added to the list unless there were programming web sites such as stackoverflow?

**UPDATE 2**

second part of the answer comes from the comment

> echo .... . json_encode(substr($string, $scan,1)); – trincot just now

obviously answer comes from 2 different people and in the form of comments.

this web site does not permit 2 comments to be chosen as a valid single answer. there is nothing i can do to stop the people from coming to this question with the hopes to answer it earn points get hired by corporations make money retire and die.

i am so sorry planet world. i failed you.

Comment: note: fixed the title so php programming language does not look like an infomercial.

Comment: it can be \n character

Comment: `'\n'` in single quotes is considered as `'\'` and `'n'`

Comment: it is true. i used double quotes and it works.

Comment: `echo .... . json_encode(substr($string, $scan,1));`

Comment: You can write your own answer, for example.

Comment: it says i can only choose my answer after 2 days. that is 2 days of people with hopes.. dreams.. thinking the question needs an answer. coming here.. and trying to earn points.. get hired by corporations.. make money to feed their lovely little girl. children. babies. wives..  lots of lots of ruined lives.. lots of misery. forgive me planet earth. this is not how i wanted it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make any character visible by outputting it in JSON encoded format, that way you will see a newline character printed as `"\n"`.

Secondly, you need to use double quotes to have PHP interpret `\n` as a new line character. With single quotes it is taken as the literal characters `\` and `n`:

```
$allowed = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n\r";
$scan = strspn($string, $allowed);

if ($scan < strlen($string)) {
    echo "problem occurs right after: $scan";
    echo "<br>the problematic character is:". 
            json_encode( substr($string, $scan,1) );
}
```